# regarding a code of creating a file object

Tags: java

I once saw the following code for creating a file object

```
File trainingFile = new File(new File(dataDir,category),category+".txt");
```

looks to me that there exists a recursive call of `new File` in the outside `new File`, what does this code exactly to do?

Answer (score 1):

it gives you a `File` object which's path is denoted by `<dataDir>/category/category.txt` where `<dataDir>` is a filepath, and `category` is a String, used both as file name and both as the most inner dir name.

It uses the constructor [File(String,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) first, and then it uses [File(File,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

The `File` constructor has an overload that takes a parent `File` object to put the new `File` in.